# xmodmap lost after sleep

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, xmodmap

In Ubuntu 18.04 I use the following autostart script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/user/.xinitrc
Version=1.0
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=xmodmap
Comment=xmodmap script
```

which just `xmodmap /path/.Xmodmap &`.

When the system boots up, it works. When the system awakes from sleep, the remapping no longer works. How can I fix this?

EDIT: (reply to a comment)
This also does not fix the issue:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/xmodmapbindings.service
[Unit]
Description=xmodmap bindings
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=-/home/norake/.xinitrc

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target

$ cat ~/.xinitrc 
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$USER" != norake ]; then
    su norake -c 'sleep 5; /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/norake/.Xmodmap' &
    # without su, without sleep, without fork (&): doesn't work either
else
    (sleep 5; /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/norake/.Xmodmap) &
fi
```

`sleep 30` doesn't work either. Of course the script run manually works.

Comment: see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend/92235#92235](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend/92235#92235)

Comment: @Andra thanks for your suggestion, see my edit

Comment: I mean, two other answers, not the one for Ubuntu14

Comment: @Andra ok, new edit :) If useful: systemd[1]: Started xmodmap bindings.
systemd[1]: xmodmapbindings.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
systemd[1]: Stopping xmodmap bindings...
systemd[1]: Stopped xmodmap bindings.

Comment: Let me add one more comment, DISPLAY=:0 does not help.

Comment: I have found the solution: `DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY`

Comment: Couldn't you add required settings to X config file, say `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-keyboard-layout.conf`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Could you elaborate with an example, bounty is still available and if it works your solution would be perfect.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need to do with xmodmap but I'm dvorak
user and my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-keyboard-layout.conf looks like
that https://pastebin.com/raw/nt917bRN

Comment: It is keymapping: CapsLock to F13.

Comment: The problem is that modern desktops use internationalization integration and remap the keyboard for multiple events including but not limited to sleep/suspend, screen lock, language change, and the wind blowing at the right speed.   The correct solution is to create a xkb keymap for your keboard, install it globally, and then switch to it in your user profile.

Answer (score 3):

Your modified settings are also "lost" when you unplug and replug the keyboard, and this is what is happening here: the suspend generates hotplug events as the keyboard is disabled when entering suspend and reenabled when exiting.

From the point of view of the X server, the keyboard connected after returning from suspend is a new keyboard, so it is brought up with the standard bindings, the same way a second keyboard would.

That is a known shortcoming of the USB keyboard drivers, and would be difficult to fix in the kernel (because USB is re-enumerated on resume, so we'd need a method of keeping the identity of a device even if it is assigned a new number), and difficult to fix in the X server (because it would need to keep a history of devices).

Likely the best thing you could do is run the command as part of your session startup and as part of hotplug processing for the keyboard, but I can't think of a fully clean solution here.

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting any input device causes the reset, which is something I hate too. It seems the real solution here is to modify keyboard layout.

Comment: Could you provide some information about how to add a script to hotplug processing?

Answer (score 1):

This is my low-tech hacky solution to a special case of this problem:

My keyboard has a Print key, where the Menu key should be, so my xmodmap remaps just that one key.

I set up a keybinding (in the gnome shell in my case) for the Print key to run

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap"
```

So after suspend, the first time I press the Print key, it will trigger xmodmap and from then on it works as a menu key.

(After that, my keyboard no longer has a Print key.)

This approach should work whenever:

1. You don't mind an initial "blind" key press.
2. You have at least one button you know you will press before or as soon as the remapping becomes relevant.
3. The initial key symbol of this button is no longer present on the new mapping.

**Update**: I have since improved my solution with xdotool to also trigger the context menu itself on the initial rebind step:

```
/bin/bash -c "xdotool keyup Print key --clearmodifiers Menu && /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap"
```

Comment: I like this solution. I use numpad-zero as control and created a *custom shortcut* in Ubuntu with this key and the command `sh -c 'xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap && notify-send Xmodmap "Xmodmap is active"'`. First time I click numpad-zero it enables Xmodmap and the second time it works as control. One issue is that having directly `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` as the command wasn't working for me because it always enabled Xmodmap instead of switching to ctrl on 2nd click, I had to wrap it with the `sh -c ''`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this post, so I could add a revision that may interest you as well: It even triggers the desired key together with the rebind on the first key press. (I remember vaguely that the rebind still behaved better in some situations, so I did not go with  xdotool only.)

Is `sh -c` any different from the `/bin/bash -c` I am using? I just tested it again with xev and see the remap the first time and then the regular Menu key.

Comment: `sh` is POSIX compliant and a subset of `bash`. In some systems it appears `sh` would point to `bash` although nowadays, at least in Ubuntu, `sh` is pointing to `dash` instead. `$ file -h /bin/sh` returns `/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash` in my case. The reason I used `sh -c` is that there is no guarantee that the path `\bin\bash -c` exists although in practice it usually does. (Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/3715151)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to replace `$USER` with your actual username:

1. Generate your `.Xmodmap` file with the mapping, in my case it is:

   ```
   keycode 96 = XF86AudioLowerVolume
   keycode 95 = XF86AudioMute
   keycode 76 = XF86AudioNext
   keycode 75 = XF86AudioPlay
   keycode 74 = XF86AudioPrev
   ```

   and place it under `/home/$USER/.Xmodmap` path
2. Create a startup application preference (go to Startup Application Preferences from super-button search menu) and add the following:

   ```
   Name: xmodmap
   Command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 7 && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap"
   Comment:
   ```

   and Save it. And close the Startup Application Preferences
3. Now go to `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep` folder, like this:

   ```shell
   cd /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
   ```
4. Create a file named `xkeyboard.sh`. You can do it like this (sudo rights are required):

   ```shell
   sudo touch xkeyboard.sh
   ```
5. Now get your `$XAUTHORITY` variable value. You can do it like this:

   ```shell
   echo $XAUTHORITY
   ```

   In my case it returned me the following:

   ```
   /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
   ```

   Write it down somewhere.
6. Open your newely created file for editing, you can do it like this:

   ```shell
   sudo nano xkeyboard.sh
   ```
7. Paste this code. Make sure to replace `$USER` with your username and `$XAUTH` with the variable you wrote down before:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   echo "Running xkeyboard.sh with argument: $1" >> /tmp/xkeyboard.log

   if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
       echo "pre" >> /tmp/xkeyboard.log
       # Nothing to do for pre-sleep
   elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
       echo "post" >> /tmp/xkeyboard.log
       export DISPLAY=:0  # Set the DISPLAY variable
       export XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH
       /bin/bash -c "sleep 7 && xmodmap home/$USER/.Xmodmap" >> /tmp/xkeyboard.log 2>&1
   fi
   ```

   In this code I've added up logging to `/tmp/xkeyboard.log` file, so if keyboard mapping doesn't work, you can go there and checkout what's the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, got help from various sources but mostly written by me. caps is the xmodmap script (CapsLock => F13).

```
#!/bin/bash

USERN=cemkalyoncu
SCRIPT=/home/cemkalyoncu/Installed/caps

case $1 in
    post)
        DISPLAY=:0
        export DISPLAY
        su $USERN -c "$SCRIPT"
        #screen
        #su $USERN -c "sleep 30; kwin --replace &" &
    esac
```

I have also left the `kwin --replace` as kwin sometimes causes glitches and it requires reset, but it is not a deamon and should be detached using screen. It is only if you are using KDE. If not installed, install screen. Exporting display here is the key to get it working. Running with your user is also necessary. Even when you are the one resuming, it is still not your account. Sleep is not necessary for xmodmap. But kwin is automatically reset by the system few seconds after resume, but sometimes fail; therefore the delay is necessary.